# How can I read a CSV file into a System.Array that has already been initialized?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I want to create an array and initialize it with for example for testing:

```
string[] myList= new string[]
{       "item1",
        "item2",        
}
```

If later I want to fill it from a csv file, will I be able to add any number of items to it ?

I don't want to use dynamic array because initialization syntax with .add method is not as convenient when I have to do it by hand.

Comment: Have you seen the [`AddRange` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.addrange.aspx)? Perhaps you'd find that more convenient. You can't seriously be refusing to use a dynamic array in the same question you ask how to use `System.Array` dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have a fixed size, so you will not be able to add any amount of numbers to it. The closest thing you can do is to create an array that is large enough to store the amount of numbers you will be most likely generating but this is highly inefficient and also prone to errors if you generate more numbers than you have initially anticipated.

You will have to use a dynamic data structure such as an ArrayList, you might not find it convenient but it is much easier and makes you code look neater and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

no , you can not add multiple items.

What  is the problem with List< string>

Comment: I don't like initialization syntax of List<string>